# Проблема с установкой CMS Битрикс "Управление сайтами", на 5 шаге устновка базы данных ошибка. Что можно сделать?

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, 1с, cms

Устанавливают эту CMS на WSL 2: Apache2 + MySQL + PHP 7.4.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дохожу до шага 5 установка базы данных и при нажатии кнопки "Далее" он мне показывает такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть перекидывает в браузере из мастера установки на эту страницу. Дальше установка не идет.

Да и до этого есть кое-что странное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на странице, определяющей все ли условия для установки продукта выполнены, показывает, что у меня версия PHP 8, хотя она у меня 7.4 на сервере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это из php.ini. Я даже не могу прочитать текст ошибки, хотя если выводить тестовый html файл в папке, куда сайт ставится, то там корректно русская кодировка отображается. в .hacctess тоже On директива про utf-8. Совсем запутался, опытыне специалисты, подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Требуется 8я, пишет что у вас  8.1.. при этом у вас она 7.4.. Есть вероятность что версия установлена не одна) положите скрипт в директорию проекта c phpinfo().. если там будет 7.4.. то установщик явно не очень качественный

Comment: ... ..settings.php означает обычно, включите "'debug' => true" в файле \bitrix\.settings.php, чтобы увидеть ошибку.

Comment: @Jour, попробовал, phpinfo() 8.1 выводит, получается, вы правы, несколько версий php почему-то работает...

Comment: @TemirStack, попадалась эта мысль, но у меня .settings.php даже не создался еще на этом этапе. Я попробовал вручную его сделать, но не помогло..

Comment: @Jour должон быть качественный дистрибутив, я его по ссылке из официальной документации скачал..

Comment: @Valentin ну мб нет базы в БД или кодировка базы корявая, не верное подключение + где-то хромает кодировка..( не имел дело с битриксом..

Comment: Как в итоге решилась проблема? У меня аналогичный случай